# How can i draw a cable with touch in Unity (like vacuum cleaner plug cable)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

I can drawing line with line renderer. But i want to pull that line with realistic effect like vacuum cleaner cable.
[video](https://youtu.be/VHuGsahqTmk?t=15) (for 5 sec)

I want to connect all the parts to body part with drawing a line. After than, they should unite with visual effect. (like vacuum cleaner cable)
I just don't know how i can make this physics
[example scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZz1b.png)

Comment: This video might help: https://youtu.be/PGk0rnyTa1U?t=278

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SY2npMqaOpc

and then Position should be the middle of the object 1 and object 2 that you want to connect.

Click on one object (pos1) with raycast
click on 2 nd object (pos2) with raycast
Now you have their positions and objects selected
connect them (i don't know how you want to be the connection)

or do it manually
separate codes for every connection

Comment: Thanks for this sharing, but like i said i can draw a line between 2 object already. But i want to add some a physic that line like a realistic rope. And i need to pull the object to other object with that rope. (as seen the photo)

Comment: I've used this in the past : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKSUhsyrj_4